# Swift: How to display a remote PDF file with multiple pages in iOS UIWebView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pdf, uiwebview

I want to display a remote multipage pdf using *UIWebView*. Here's what I do in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = true
self.webView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
let url : NSURL! = NSURL(string: pdfFile)
webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url ))
```

`webview` is an instance of *UIWebView* and the string `pdfFile` contains the URL to the pdf on a remote server.

When I run this, the view shows but the first page of the pdf. How do I display all the pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct. Does the PDF file work in Safari/iOS?

There are quite a few known problems with Apple's CoreGraphics PDF renderer - it's absolutely possible that you simply run into such an issue and it incorrectly parsers the file. Also possible that the file itself is slightly corrupt, yet Adobe Acrobat has many workarounds to deal with such files, when other parsers often are less resilient. I know this space pretty well since I spent pretty much all of my time for the last 5 years on PSPDFKit, which is a 3rd-party SDK for rendering and editing/annotating PDF documents on iOS, that you can use much like the code above. (Just with a [`PSPDFViewController`](https://pspdfkit.com/api/ios/Classes/PSPDFViewController.html) instead of `UIWebView`).

It's a commercial solution and we have a team of 25 people working on it - we wrote our own PDF renderer after we found too many defects and problems with Apple's renderer. Most open source solutions you can find will use `CGPDF` and will exhibit the same issues as `UIWebView`.

If all you're looking for is a bit more control but the rendering is fine, and you do not need smart zoom, text selection or search, take a look at Apple's [ZoomingPDFViewer example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) - which will get you started how to best use `CGContextDrawPDFPage` to draw PDF and allow zooming. (Fair warning, it will be quite slow if you don't write your own caching layer.)

Sometimes, opening the PDF in Apple Preview and simply re-saving it will also fix your issues, as this process rewrites the whole tree. You'll loose much data such as PDF widgets and some annotations, but in some cases this is good enough to correct partially broken documents so they can be rendered fine on mobile. We have [a support article about 3rd-party support](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/miscellaneous/3rd-party-compatibility/?search=3rd) where you can learn more about this as well.

Comment: My code was indeed correct, there was a problem with the url.